# Error while building/deploying project TCPServer (kit: Desktop) When executing step "qmake"

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I create a project called TCPServer that simulate an server in a comunication TCP in a computer and the code worked, but when I move it in an other computer and I compile the code, I receive the following message.

```
Error while building/deploying project TCPServer (kit: Desktop) 
When executing step "qmake"
```

I suppose that the promblem is caused by the moving.
Does anyone know how I can solve the problem?

[THIS IS THE LINK OF FILE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByoYvBb9Z3NIRG50TjlHLUhsWUk)

Answer (score 0):

I've already had this problem in a similar project. You should delete the directories TCPServer.pro.user and TCPServer.pro.user.0011e05.xml . 
After that open TCPServer.pro from qtcreator and it will run.